# installing ruby 1.9.3-p194 using rbenv on centos 6.7

Tags: centos6, openssl, ruby

I'm moving a Ruby/Rails app to a Centos 6.7 server (from Ubuntu) and am installing ruby via rbenv.

I run `rbenv install -v 1.9.3-p194` and it will start to compile but the build fails.  The build output log gives the following output showing a failed build.

```
ossl_pkey_ec.c:816: error: ‘EC_GROUP_new_curve_GF2m’ undeclared (first use in this function)
ossl_pkey_ec.c:816: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
ossl_pkey_ec.c:816: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[2]: *** [ossl_pkey_ec.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
```

I have all of the development tools installed on the box and also have openssl-devel installed and it matches the Centos version.  But I'm sort of hitting a wall here.

Has anyone had problems with this before and if so, how can I fix it?  Full output in pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/wXJkwFwY)

Comment: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki#make-error-for-200-p247-and-lower-on-fedorared-hat

Comment: Thanks, but I've already installed all of the required packages for centos to for rbenv and ruby-build to run.  When i try to reinstall it's noted they are already installed.  And the link to the patch how does this apply to 1.9.3-p194?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known issue with the openssl headers and certain operating systems.  I ran the following command for a successful build merging a patch in.

`curl -fsSL "https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/0d58bb55985e787364b0235e5e69278d0f0ad4b0.patch" |   filterdiff -x a/ChangeLog | rbenv install --patch -v 1.9.3-p194`